# How to filter the array json in Ext js 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

Consider this as my json data. 
I want to filter the "gridValues" in the data using value "LAN". I have used Ext js filter method. It doesn't return the filter data.

```
var tableData = [
                {
                    "TABLE_TITLE": "Details",
                    "tableColumns": {
                        "COLUMNNAME_0": "Interface",
                        "COLUMNNAME_1": "Conversation",
                        "COLUMNNAME_2": "Data Flow(KB)"

                    },
                    "gridValues": [
                        {
                            "COLUMVal_0": "LAN",
                            "COLUMVal_1": "192.168.9.113 to 61.16.173.233",
                            "COLUMVal_2": "1132.7"

                        },
                        {
                            "COLUMVal_0": "TATA",
                            "COLUMVal_1": "192.168.8.67 to 111.221.115.98",
                            "COLUMVal_2": "619.72"

                        },
                        {
                            "COLUMVal_0": "CITI",
                            "COLUMVal_1": "192.168.8.60 to 23.6.112.201",
                            "COLUMVal_2": "619.2"

                        }

                    ]
                }
            ];
```

I used the following code for filtering data:

```
var arry =[]; 
var fliterarry =[]; 
var i,u; 
for (i=0;i<tableData.length;i++) {
    arry.push(tableData[i].gridValues);
    } 
var arryFtr = arry.filter(function(e){ 
for (u=0;u<e.length;u++) { 
    if(e[u].COLUMVal_0 === 'TATA'){ 
      tableData[u].gridValues.push(e[u]); 
     } 
    return e[u].COLUMVal_0 == 'TATA';
 } 
return fliterarry 
});
```

Comment: Please post the "Ext js filter method" you called.

Comment: Filter Code

    var arry =[];
 var fliterarry =[];
 var i,u;
 for (i=0;i<tableData.length;i++)
 {
  arry.push(tableData[i].gridValues);
 }
 var arryFtr = arry.filter(function(e){
  for (u=0;u<e.length;u++)
  {  
    if(e[u].COLUMVal_0 === 'TATA'){
     tableData[u].gridValues.push(e[u]);
    }
    return e[u].COLUMVal_0 == 'TATA';
  }
  return fliterarry
 });

Comment: You want to filter 'LAN' or 'TATA'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to filter data with COLUMVal_0 equals "TATA" , right ?

Try following codes in your function :

```
var filterArray = [];
for ( tdKey in tableData ) {
    for ( gvKey in tableData[tdKey].gridValues ) {
        if ( tableData[tdKey].gridValues[gvKey].COLUMVal_0 == "TATA" ) {
            filterArray.push(tableData[tdKey].gridValues[gvKey]);
        }
    }
}
return fliterarry;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, its working but how can i replace the filterArray  in the tableData of "gridValues" values

Comment: Do like this  Ext.decode(tableData).gridvalues = filterArray and then if you need then again encode tableData. You data will be updated.